# Error "The parameter location has an invalid value" when deploying ARM, resource gets created anyway

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-bicep

I have a full development Azure environment setup, and I've exported the templates in order to create a Live environment that I can maintain using DevOps pipelines.

Everything is located in "West Europe", and the templates have been exported as such. My templates for storage, cosmos db, appinsights have all been deployed successfully, but as soon as I hit the function apps, things fall apart...

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (DeploymentFailed) At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
Code: DeploymentFailed
Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
Exception Details:      (BadRequest) {
          "Code": "BadRequest",
          "Message": "The parameter location has an invalid value.",
          "Target": null,
          "Details": [
            {
              "Message": "The parameter location has an invalid value."
            },
            {
              "Code": "BadRequest"
            },
            {
              "ErrorEntity": {
                "ExtendedCode": "51008",
                "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
                "Parameters": [
                  "location"
                ],
                "Code": "BadRequest",
                "Message": "The parameter location has an invalid value."
              }
            }
          ],
          "Innererror": null
        }
```

I've tried (I think) all different possibilities:

- Hardcoded value for location ("West Europe", "westeurope", resourceGroup().location)
- using a location param with the same different values as defaults
- using the location param but without defaults, values injected through AZ CLI script

It keeps giving me this error and I'm losing my mind over it...
And the worst part is, in Azure Portal, I can see the Function App being created, in the correct region of West Europe... But my pipeline script fails of course so I'm stuck in a loop...

I'm using the following bicep script:

```
param function_app_name string
param serverfarm_name string
param location string = 'West Europe'

resource serverfarm_name_resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-03-01' existing = {
    name: serverfarm_name
}

resource function_app_name_resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
    name: function_app_name
    location: location
    kind: 'functionapp'
    properties: {
        enabled: true
        hostNameSslStates: [{
                name: '${function_app_name}.azurewebsites.net'
                sslState: 'Disabled'
                hostType: 'Standard'
            }{
                name: '${function_app_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net'
                sslState: 'Disabled'
                hostType: 'Repository'
            }
        ]
        serverFarmId: serverfarm_name_resource.id
        reserved: false
        isXenon: false
        hyperV: false
        siteConfig: {
            numberOfWorkers: 1
            acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: false
            alwaysOn: false
            http20Enabled: false
            functionAppScaleLimit: 200
            minimumElasticInstanceCount: 1
        }
        scmSiteAlsoStopped: false
        clientAffinityEnabled: false
        clientCertEnabled: false
        clientCertMode: 'Required'
        hostNamesDisabled: false
        customDomainVerificationId: 'D66FAC927CFA4699149BB60D0F4CC216EF611163A384850BDEEE5B52D35CCF63'
        containerSize: 1536
        dailyMemoryTimeQuota: 0
        httpsOnly: true
        redundancyMode: 'None'
        storageAccountRequired: false
        keyVaultReferenceIdentity: 'SystemAssigned'
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct location name here is westeurope. You said you already tried that but did you get the exact same error message or a slightly different one ?

Comment: The exact same error message for all different variations that I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying `serverfarm_name_resource.location`?

or just specfiying any value since the location is from the existing resource, any value would work and pass validation?!

Not sure if this is the same or similar issue
https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4815

Comment: For the serverfarm location I get the following validation in the editor already:
This expression is being used in an assignment to the "location" property of the "Microsoft.Web/sites" type, which requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment. Properties of serverfarm_name_resource which can be calculated at the start include "apiVersion", "id", "name", "type".

Comment: It's also not the same issue I think, because if I enter a completely random value I get an error which contains a list of all allowed values (get this... including "westeurope") for that resourcetype (functionapp)... BUT if I try with westeurope the original error message remains...

Comment: That's........odd! I'd probably be inclined to raise a new issue on the repo and refence #4815 to say it's similar but not entirely the same. There was an upstream issue they were tracking to fix that bug which _may_ be related.